# My ETH transaction doesn't appears

Tags: ether, exchanges, poloniex

I have an account in poloniex and i transferred 0.1 ETH to another account but it doesn't appear.
here are the images.
[image: Transaction from poloniex]

[image: My wallet empty]

Comment: They have problems today with Ether withdrawals and deposits as well. If there is no transaction on the chain yet I think all you can do is open a support ticket.

Comment: thx, you mean in poloniex right?

Comment: Yes, I have 10 ether stuck there for about 8 hours now. Still no response for my ticket. People are complaining with the same problem all over in the trollbox.

Comment: still nothing new from poloniex team. 48 hours that ether deposit is stuck and all they send is this msg without answering with support. [![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ks3bb.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ks3bb.png)

Comment: Please talk to poloniex support, not much we can do here.